# Convert Row data to columns in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have data in my List like below
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfiJ5.png)

I want to convert that data like this [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMrIi.png) and also Same project should be in same color.

is it possible to do it through coding? Can anybody help me I have no idea how to get the expected output. I'm using MVC Linq and Entity Framework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us what you have done so far, add some code and the results. Make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

of course you must write custom code

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   // Weeks of the month
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
      // ToDo build another collection
   }
}
```